# Sql query number of occurrence

Tags: sql-server-2005

I wanna to have query:

```
Select cars.* from cars where cars.code in
(
select carCode from articles where 
numberofrecords with this car (it is not a column) >1
and Accepted=1
order by date
)
```

How to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cars c
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT carCode 
        FROM articles
        WHERE Accepted = 1
        GROUP BY carCode
        HAVING COUNT(carCode) > 1
    ) a ON c.code = a.carCode
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT  cars.*
FROM    cars
WHERE   cars.code IN (
    SELECT  carCode
    FROM    articles
    WHERE   Accepted = 1
    GROUP BY carCode
    HAVING COUNT(articleId) > 1
)
```